# Oracle DateTime in Where Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, time, date-arithmetic

I have sql something like this:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TIME_CREATED >= TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy')
```

-> This returns 10 rows and TIME_CREATED = '26-JAN-2011'

Now when i do this i don't get any rows back,

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE TIME_CREATED = TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy')
```

-> Took the greater than out

Any reason why?

Comment: You should avoid language dependent date formats. That can cause trouble on different systems. You should use `01` instead of `JAN` (plus the approriate format of course) to make sure your code runs without problem on any system.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Yes: TIME_CREATED contains a date and a **time**. Use `TRUNC` to strip the time:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TRUNC(TIME_CREATED) = TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy')
```

**UPDATE:**
As Dave Costa points out in the comment below, this will prevent Oracle from using the index of the column `TIME_CREATED` if it exists. An alternative approach without this problem is this:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TIME_CREATED >= TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy') 
      AND TIME_CREATED < TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy') + 1
```

Comment: Note that this approach will prevent the use of an index on TIME_CREATED, if one exists.

Comment: Thank you posting the solution.  It was quick and easy to find.

While I have worked on other DBMS such as Ingres, MS-SQL, MS-Access, and DB2, I have not worked with Oracle before my current assignment.

Comment: Why not use `BETWEEN TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy') + 1`?

Comment: @ajeh: I don't like `between` because of the ambiguity. It sounds as if it is exclusive the bounds when in fact it is inclusive. That's why I avoid it. Furthermore, in this concrete example, it wouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 40):

You can also use the following to include the TIME portion in your query:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME
     , DEPT
  FROM EMPLOYEE 
 WHERE TIME_CREATED >= TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011 00:00:00', 'dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 18):

You could also do:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TRUNC(TIME_CREATED) = DATE '2011-01-26'
```

Answer (score 9):

This is because a `DATE` column in Oracle also contains a time part. The result of the `to_date()` function is a date with the time set to `00:00:00` and thus it probably doesn't match any rows in the table.

You should use:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE trunc(TIME_CREATED) = TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 6):

As other people have commented above, using TRUNC will prevent the use of indexes (if there was an index on TIME_CREATED). To avoid that problem, the query can be structured as

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, DEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE TIME_CREATED BETWEEN TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy') 
            AND TO_DATE('26/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy') + INTERVAL '86399' second;
```

86399 being 1 second less than the number of seconds in a day.