# query by day in PL/SQL(oracle)

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I am querying from database:

```
select * from database where id = 12345
```

and i get a couple of days where it is equal to
3/4/2010 9:16:59 AM

but if i add
and date = to_date('03/04/2010','DD/MM/YYYY')

giving me

```
select * from database where id = 12345
and date = to_date('03/04/2010','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I comeback with completely nothing.

Any pointers?
btw, I know that there is a time on there, but I don't know how to compare just based on the day!!!

Comment: Are you positive that when you look at date and get "3/4/2010 9:16:59 AM" that the format is DD/MM... and not the weird American MM/DD....?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle DateTime in Where Clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749369/oracle-datetime-in-where-clause)

Comment: Dear Shannon, I wish if I took your advice earlier. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WHERE id = 12345
   AND date >= TO_DATE('03/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
   AND date <  TO_DATE('03/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates

Comment: That's one weird way of answering it... but it doens't work for me? I haven't seen +1, how does the database know you are trying to add a day?

Comment: @Kevin still giving no result? I forgot to include your ID clause. reg +1: oracle calculated DATE type always in days. But you can use + INVERVAL '1' DAY as well, if you prefer.

Comment: I've included my id to make the query as  select * from table where id = 123 and date >= TO_DATE('03/03/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
   AND date <  TO_DATE('03/03/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1

Comment: Sadly, It's still not working for me. I'm not sure why, i use the PL/SQL developer under oracle. not working! sigh. Thanks for your help though, maybe I am missing something

Comment: @Kevin It goes well and it let Oracle use the index; if it exists and if it's of a some importance for a consistent data volume in your table.

Comment: Wow, Okay so I just noticed that the database is stored MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: That was why my queries wasn't working, 12 hours of staring at the computer for something small right? Haha I just started this job so that's my excuse :D

Answer (score 3):

That's because when you are creating the date, you implicitly set the time to 0:00:00, and as 0:00:00 is not equal to 9:16:59, you'll not get the date returned.

To tell Oracle to ignore the time part, just do the following:

```
WHERE id = 12345
  AND trunc(date) = to_date('03/04/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```