# Oracle date comparison in where clause

Tags: oracle, date

For eg I have a student table with a DOJ(date of joining) column with its type set as DATE now in that I have stored records in dd-mon-yy format.

I have an IN param at runtime with date passed as string and its in dd/mm/yyyy format. How do I compare and fetch results on date?

I want to fetch count of records of students who have DOJ of 25-AUG-92 per my database table student, but I am getting date as varchar in dd/mm/yyyy format in an IN param, kindly please guide.

I have tried multiple options such as `trunc`, `to_date`, `to_char` but, unfortunately nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a student table with a DOJ(date of joining) column with its type set as `DATE` now in that I have stored records in `dd-mon-yy` format.

Not quite, the `DATE` data-type does not have a format; it is stored internally in tables as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle) (year is 2 bytes and month, day, hour, minute and second are 1-byte each). The user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/PLUS, SQL Developer, Toad, etc.) will handle the formatting of a `DATE` from its binary format to a human readable format. In SQL/Plus (or SQL Developer) this format is based on the [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547559/1509264).

If the `DATE` is input using only the day, month and year then the time component is (probably) going to be set to `00:00:00` (midnight).

> I have an IN param at runtime with date passed as string or say varchar and its in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. How do I compare and fetch results on date.?

Assuming the time component for you DOJ column is always midnight then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   students
WHERE  doj = TO_DATE( your_param, 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
```

If it isn't always midnight then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   students
WHERE  TRUNC( doj ) = TO_DATE( your_param, 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   students
WHERE  doj >= TO_DATE( your_param, 'dd/mm/yyyy' )
AND    doj <  TO_DATE( your_param, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Comment: Great answer..  you might want to add that the `TRUNC(doj)` option would prevent Oracle from using most indexes on `doj`, which is why your last option is often seen in practice, despite being longer and more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The below *should* do what you've described. If not, provide more information on how "nothing seems to work".

```
-- Get the count of students with DOJ = 25-AUG-1992
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM STUDENT
WHERE TRUNC(DOJ) = TO_DATE('25/AUG/1992','dd/mon/yyyy');
```

The above was pulled from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749403/2654498). You may want to look at the answer, because if performance is critical to you, there is a different way to write this query which doesn't use `trunc`, which will allow Oracle to use index on DOJ, if one is present.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am bit late in posting this but I have been able to resolve this.

What I did was I converted both the dates to_char in similar formats and it worked here is my query condition that worked..

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(C.DOB, 'DD-MON-YY'),'DD-MON-YY')=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(P_Dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY'))
```

Thanks for the support all. :)